# Change default paragraph headings programmatically for Google Docs with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've been searching for this feature for quite awhile now.
Basically, I'd like to change the default paragraph styles for Title, Subtitle, Heading 1 and so on.

I know it is possible with the Google Docs interface (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/116338?hl=en), but as far as I know not programatically with Apps Script.

Did anyone find a solution for this yet? And if not, can we submit it as a feature request for the Google Apps script team? It would be a great addition to the already existing Apps Script Docs API for branding purposes.

Comment: you can make a copy from a template

Comment: That would solve the issue for new documents, not existing ones.

Comment: yes, but its the only way you can currently achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now this is possible with the [setHeadingAttributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#setHeadingAttributes(ParagraphHeading,Object)) method. For example, here I redefine the styles of Heading levels 1 and 2.

```
  myHeading1 = {};
  myHeading1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 24;
  myHeading1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = "Georgia";

  myHeading2 = {};
  myHeading2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 16;
  myHeading2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = "Verdana";
  myHeading2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = "#555555";

  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.setHeadingAttributes(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1, myHeading1);
  body.setHeadingAttributes(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2, myHeading2);
```

It doesn't seem possible to reset the attributes back to their default, so if you think that a reset will be needed, get the original attributes with [getHeadingAttributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getHeadingAttributes(ParagraphHeading)) and store them in document properties.

Note that changing heading attributes does not immediately affect already existing headings: they stay with their current style unless someone touches their heading level (i.e., selects something from the heading level drop-down, even the same level as the current one). To apply the changes retroactively to existing paragraphs, see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/112792).